# Establish trust between two azure AD

Tags: azure, azure-active-directory

Is there any way to establish a two-way trust between multi-domain ADs in azure.

example one AD with abc.com and other in xyz.com.

Can I establish a trust between them and use the users from any of the domain directly into my SharePoint site.?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There is no "trust" but there is a mechanism for it - it is called Azure AD B2B. 
I've covered it in my blog post - http://predica.pl/blog/guests-in-the-cloud-how-to-safely-manage-external-users-using-azure-ad-b2b/ - you can use it as starting point.

There is feature for AAD B2B in the making which will allow you to "invite" entire domain (other tenant) as guests at once. This will be as close you can get to the trust in Azure AD environment as it can be.